# Document to Markdown using PHP

Tags: php, markdown

I was wondering is there a way to convert a document(doc or docx), which contains images and text into a markdown.
Ex: Document contains an Image and description for that image
I was trying to convert that document into a markdown such as follows

```
<img src="doument_name/media/image1.png" width="624" height="505" />
Followed by description with markdown
```

When I search, I only found Markdown parser's, converters which convert text data into HTML

Comment: Open it in Microsoft Word and use 'Save as...', then select HTML. If needed, there are converters from HTML to markdown.

Comment: I would like to this in dynamic, i.e., create doc dynamically and use it right away

Answer (score 0):

Doc and Docx are complex proprietary formats, and markdown is not widely used. Converting one to the other directly will be difficult. It's better to use HTML as the intermediate step.

There are many PHP solutions out there to read MS-docs, but, as you perhaps have found, they're all slightly flawed. They also don't do the conversion to HTML, they read, but don't convert, or they don't include images, etc.

As an alternative you could try an online API, like:

http://apiv2.online-convert.com/

I haven't tested this, but it could be a good solution: It converts to HTML, and you have to write, and maintain, very little code yourself.

The conversion from HTML to markdown is relatively easy, you can find examples online:

https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown

https://github.com/Elephant418/Markdownify